# Por qué VB no valida los datos nulos

Tags: base-de-datos, vba, ms-access, vb, null

verán tengo un script en vba que ejecuta una consulta en access y lo que intento hacer es validar que si algún dato es nulo, este entre en cierta condición y actualice ese registro a un texto "N/A" sin embargo vb no valida esta función, ya que al momento de traer un dato nulo, no lo interpreta como nulo y salta la condición pero en algunos casos si lo hace. Cabe mencionar que al momento de ejecutar el código con un breakPoint y pasar el mouse sobre mi variable x, esta me dice que x = Nulo asi, textualmente Nulo

```
Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSQL)

For i = 0 To 19
       If datos.Fields(i) Is Nothing Or datos.Fields(i) = "" Or datos.Fields(i) = Null Then
           x = datos.Fields(i)
           datos.Fields(i) = "N/A"
       End If
Next
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué no entra en la condición si sencillamente el valor es nulo. Probé con nothing o "" por si por alguno de esos casos entraba a la condición pero no logro encontrar el porqué. De antemano les agradezco por su apoyo.
Excelente tarde.

Comment: Nulo como esta descripto ahi no es lo mismo que nothing ni lo mismo que "" ni lo mismo que null.. Que tipo de datos tiene x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usar el operador `=` significa que intentará comparar el valor, pero no puede comparar un valor con Null de esta manera. Para este caso puede utilizar la función `isNull`, así el código quedaría de esta manera:

```
Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSQL)

For i = 0 To 19
    If datos.Fields(i) Is Nothing Or datos.Fields(i) = "" Or isNull(datos.Fields(i)) Then
       x = datos.Fields(i)
       datos.Fields(i) = "N/A"
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Bro! muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta, no encontraba esa manera de comparar un valor con un null. Pero de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: @UseIP que bueno que resolvió ... con gusto

Answer (score 1):

Para validar un valor null en vb se utiliza **Nothing**, este representa el valor predeterminado del tipo de dato que se emplea, en este caso la validación sería

```
If (a is Nothing) Then 
 ...
End If
```

También se puede declarar el método IsNullOrEmpty de la clase String.

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(a) Then
 . ..
 End If
```